# why we going for sqlcommandbuilder?

Tags: sqldataadapter, sqlcommandbuilder

Option 1: to insert data in a db

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_name(eid,eName,Dept) values('"+ textBox1.Text +"','"+ textBox2.Text +"','"+ Textbox3.Text +"'", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Option 2:

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table_name",con);

SqlCommandBuilder sqlcomb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlda);

DataSet dset = new DataSet("table1");

sqlda.Fill(dset,"table1");

DataRow drow = dset.Tables["table1"].NewRow();
drow["eid"] = textBox1.Text.ToString();
drow["eName"] = textBox2.Text.ToString();
drow["Dept"] = textBox3.Text.ToString();

dset.Tables["table1"].Rows.Add(drow);

sqlda.Update(dset, "table1");
```

My question is, I feel like option1 is best method to insert.. why we using `SqlCommandBuilder` to insert data? What is the use of SqlCommandBuilder? Any advantages in inserting the data using `SqlCommandBuilder`? your suggestion plz

Answer (score 2):

I would always go for **option 3: parametrized queries** !!

> **DO NOT CONCATENATE TOGETHER YOUR SQL STATEMENTS** - **N E V E R**

If you do - see [what **will** happen eventually.....](http://xkcd.com/327/)

They are both safe against SQL injection attacks, and more efficient (since a single query plan can be reused if you call this with several parameter values):

```
string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.table_name(eid, eName, Dept) " + 
                    "VALUES(@eid, @eName, @dept)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@eid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = .......;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = .......;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dept", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = .......;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or then **option 4 : use an ORM** (object-relational mapper) like [Dapper-Dot-Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) to get your relational data into nice objects for use in .NET (and finally forget about messing around with `DataRow` and `DataColumn` and such stuff) ??